# sk-learn saved model to disk, but get only array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

When storing a `fitted_clf` sk-learn classifier like:

```
joblib.dump(fitted_clf, some_path)
```

Most of the time when loading it back into memory like:

```
joblib.load(some_path)
```

only an array of `array(['col1', 'col2], dtype=object)` is returned instead of loading the fitted pipeline.

However, sometimes I get the real pipeline, but do not understand why this is not a consistent behavior.

## edit

I think this has to do with different joblib verisions i.e.
from `sklearn.externals import joblib` works, but when using regular `joblib` I only get an array

Answer (score 4):

confirmed. Using `sklearn.externals import joblib` is fixing this to have consistent behavior.